# Copying found directory to path built using specified argument and found directory

Tags: linux, bash, find, exec, cp

I have the following bash script:

```
cd root_folder && find folder1 folder2 -name "doc" -exec cp -r --parents {} $1{} \;
```

The idea is to find all folders named `doc` under `folder1` and `folder2` and copying the structure starting from `root_folder` to the path which is specified by the user's argument (along with all the content of `doc`).

So for example

```
root_folder/folder1/other_folder/doc
```

becomes:

```
$1/folder1/other_folder/doc
```

This script works as long as I don't have the user specify the folder to be copied to, i.e. if I don't have the `$1`. However when I do have it, I get the error:

```
cp: with --parents, the destination must be a directory
Try `cp --help' for more information.
```

This despite the fact that 1) I have assured that the specified folder exists beforehand, and 2) If I output the full path to be copied to, it looks exactly as it should, i.e. `$1/folder1/other_folder/doc`.

I have also tried adding a `/` after `$1` to make `$1/{}`, but that gives a forward slash too many, making the path contain `//` which is obviously wrong.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was adding `dirname` to the destination path:

```
cd root_folder && find folder1 folder2 -name "doc" -exec cp -r --parents {} `dirname $1/{}` \;
```